# Laravel update Sql for a single column with all rows

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
i want to update all the value of siteView column.i am useing laravel 5.4
```

Any help will be appreciated.
here is my database table.
[database table (click to see the table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dlUO.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your problem / question?

Comment: i just want to change all the siteView column value with any Other values like 6 will be 10 8 will be 99 etc.
i don't understand how to write the update sql

Answer (score 3):

You can update everything that matches a specific query by calling the update function at the end of any query Builder instance.

For example, say you want to change all siteViews that are now 6 to 7:

```
YourModelName::where('siteView', 6)->update(['siteView' => 7]);
```

In case you want to update **all** rows you can also call update on ::query directly:

```
YourModelName::query()->update(['siteView' => 8]);
```

You can read more about this update functionality here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates

Comment: i actually want to update all the value of siteView column by a single query

Comment: Added an example for how to do it without the where.

Comment: `DB::table('videos')->whereIn('Id',$array)->update($array);`
something like that

Comment: That looks like it should work. Although I can imagine that, based on your database engine, the whereIn may cause an error in this case because the column is actually 'id' with a lowercase i.

Comment: that my writing mistake .i wrote `id` ;problem is in my second $array

`array:4 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "siteView" => 8
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "siteView" => 8
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "siteView" => 7
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "siteView" => 9
  ]
]`

this is my second array.it shows me "Array to String Conversion".error

Comment: When you do a batch update you can't actually provide a different value for every row. However, if you only want to add 1 to the siteView you could use 'siteView' => DB::raw('siteView + 1'). This will increment every row's siteView by 1.

Comment: then what will i do?there is no other way to update all the values with different values

Comment: In that case using a foreach over YourModelName::all() is your best bet. Although honestly, I can't think of a single situation where you would want to set all rows in your table to a value at the same time where the value isn't derived from another column (or the same). So explaining the actual problem you're trying to solve might make it easier to properly answer your question.